# Javascript Replace a value with something else, any advice?

Tags: javascript, string, discord

How can I replace the string `message.guild.region` which returns different regions (for example: europe, brazil, japan, russia, etc) and make it return those Regions but instead with the first letter capital (for example: Europe, Brazil, Japan, Russian, etc)? Any help is welcome, sorry if something isn't clear. I will try to explain it as best as I can.

Here's my code:

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}serverinfo`)) {
        const serverinfoembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(`#a87f32`)
        .setTitle(`${message.guild.name}`)
        .addFields(
        { name: '**Owner**', value: `${message.guild.owner}`, inline: true },
        { name: '**Region**', value: `${message.guild.region}`, inline: true },
        { name: '**Members**', value: `${message.guild.memberCount}`, inline: true },
        )
        .setFooter(`ID: ${message.guild.id} | Server Created • ${message.guild.createdAt.toDateString()}`)
        message.channel.send(serverinfoembed)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it to this function:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need this:

[How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Then use the `map` function:

```
newRegions = regions.map(region => upperCaseFirst(region);
```